# net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeChunkDownloader : Timeout waiting for the download of #chunk0

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

Getting timeout waiting for download of chunk error. Snowflake JDBC driver version: 3.13.18
error encountered:

```
*net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException*: JDBC driver internal error: Timeout waiting for the download of #chunk0(Total chunks: 4) retry=0.
Encountered an error while trying to retrieve the list of event log records. JDBC driver internal error: Timeout waiting for the download of #chunk0(Total chunks: 4) retry=0.
```

Comment: It looks your client is not able to reach the internal stage to download the result set. Do you have a proxy in between? I would suggest you run [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html) and see if your network has any filtering.

Comment: @Sergiu I have multiple queries in the application which are running properly. Even with this query if I limit the output rows, I am getting the result. The issue only occurs when output result set is too big, say >1000 rows.

Comment: Queries that return a small result set are served directly, queries with large result sets are storing the result set temporarily on an internal stage and the client connector/driver is directed to retrieve the resultset from that stage. That stage uses a different URL than the Snowflake account (it's an S3 URL or an Azure blob storage URL) and if that URL is somehow filtered by a proxy in your network you might get this issue. Run SnowCD as I mentioned and you will see if the proxy is causing the issue.

Comment: @Sergiu Any idea how we can get that intermediate URL ? I tried looking into Spark logs, but couldn't fetch it.
FYI - I am using AWS Glue for my job

Comment: The URL is returned by the function [SYSTEM$WHITELIST](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_whitelist.html) and it's the one marked as "type":"STAGE".

Comment: @sergiu Is this mechanism documented anywhere? I have also run into this, and the debug logs show me the URLs it's trying (and failing due to firewall) to access, but I wish I could have learned about this mechanism from documentation rather than through debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the timeout parameter https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-parameters.html#querytimeout

Comment: Thanks for your time! But the default value of the parameter is zero which specifies that driver should wait indefinitely as per documentation. And I am using default value only.

Comment: This is not related to timeout as you're on the download part of the chunks and at retry 0, so it's more network related (proxy in general).