# Snowflake JDBC ResultSet with more than 1000 rows not reaching Client

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Our Application is fetching data From Snowflake privatelink account using JDBC queries , the app is running behind a restricted firewall and proxy , When we run SnowCD it shows many URL are blocked , but if we pass proxy information in snowcd then it succesfully pass all test.

Now when we run our app to connect snowflake and execute queries , those queries which returns small data executes but those who returns large data (3000 rows+) goes in waiting , and after long wait timeout error comes.
Same queries works when data is small.

[net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeChunkDownloader : Timeout waiting for the download of #chunk0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72173856/net-snowflake-client-jdbc-snowflakechunkdownloader-timeout-waiting-for-the-dow)

From this stackoverflow discussion I came to know, that when snowflake JDBC execute a small resultset the response comes directly , if its a large resultset a separate request goes to Internal stage (aws s3) and that url is different than snowflake account url  , and if proxy is there this might create problem. Private link don't need proxy parameters but STAGE url's need proxy.

But when i am trying proxy properties in JDBC Url and Tomcat level as well there is no difference, it's not working.

I didn't found any proper Snowflake Documentation to explain this Large ResultSet vs Small Result Set behavior.

Comment: Large result sets are stored on an internal stage of your Snowflake account and the driver is instructed to download them from there. This is done for several reasons, but in general it concerns performance. Now, when you run in Snowflake UI the function SYSTEM$ALLOWLIST_PRIVATELINK one of the parameters **"type":"STAGE"** shows you the stage URL that you need to allow via your proxy/firewall. Result sets bigger than 100KB usually are stored on the internal stage, see also [this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/2021-02-bcr#access-to-persisted-large-query-results-reduced-to-6-hours)